# Select distinct from the table and sort by date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to built the messaging system and I want to select distinct value from the table and sort by date and also return the read and unread status. My table structure is as `id, from_user_id, to_user_id, message, datetime, read` . Suppose dummy data are as follows:

```
id   |   from_user_id  | to_user_id   |  message  |      datetime       | read
1    |          20     |     50       |    hi     |  2016-3-13 06:05:30 | 1
2    |          20     |     50       |    hey     |  2016-3-13 06:15:30 | 0
3    |          30     |     50       |    hi     |  2016-3-14 06:05:30 | 0
```

Now I want to select distinct `from_user_id` and sort by date so that I can display the name of the user who is chating recently on top of list and also return the read status 1, if any of the rows with `from_user_id` has read status 0, then I want to return `read` as 0 so that I can differentiate whose user message has unread message.

Suppose, `from_user_id` has `read` status as 0 in one rows then I want to return `read` status as 0 when returning distinct value of `from_user_id`. How can I do it. I tried as follows but won't work in my case. It returns distinct value but not sorted by date and also read status in not returning what I expect.

```
 select distinct(`from_user_id`),register.name FROM message INNER JOIN register ON register.id = message.from_user_id where message.to_user_id = $user_id GROUP BY message.id ORDER BY MAX(datetime) ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
message.from_user_id,
register.name,
message.read
FROM message 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT  
   from_user_id,
   MAX(datetime) max_datetime
  FROM message 
  WHERE to_user_id = 50
  GROUP BY from_user_id ) t
 ON t.from_user_id = message.from_user_id AND t.max_datetime = message.datetime
INNER JOIN register ON register.id = message.from_user_id
WHERE message.to_user_id = 50
ORDER BY message.datetime ASC
```

[**UPDATED SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fe74/3/0)

**Sample Input:**

```
id   |   from_user_id  | to_user_id   |  message  |      datetime        | read
```

---

```
1    |          20     |     50       |    hi     |  2016-3-13 06:05:30  | 1
2    |          20     |     50       |    hey    |  2016-3-13 06:15:30  | 0
3    |          30     |     50       |    hi     |  2016-3-14 06:05:30  | 0
```

**Output:**

```
from_user_id        name        read
```

---

```
20                 User20      0
30                 User30      0
```

**Note:** This query might give you multiple row for the same `from_user_id` if there exists multiple entries in your `message` table having the same `datetime` and same `to_user_id`.

Comment: Please check the updated sql fiddle. I've modified the query too. Please check this update. @user254153

Comment: you mean if `to_user_id` and `datetime` is same for two rows, it may return multiple `from_user_id`. But, how can it be solved. I want to select only distinct.

Comment: Actually this case won't arise unless you have invalid state of data like `having the same from_user_id,datetime and to_user_id` in multiple rows. Is it possible in your case?@user254153

Comment: It might be very rare case. But I may solve this, if I make my datetime field very unique. Suppose if user send two message in same time with ajax  then there may be repeatition in datetime if it is inserted with same datetime. I can ensure that datetime is very unique. So even user send two message at same time, Can I make increment in second if there is already same datetime.

Comment: No you are misunderstanding my point. If a single user sends the same message twice or more to the same recipient accidentally. Actually this situation won't appear unless something unexpected occurs. Please don't be bothered with this. I've said such in order to show my query behavior. Just ignore it dude! @user254153

Answer (score 0):

checkout this query :

**SELECT DISTINCT(form_user_id),MIN(read) FROM table_name ORDER BY datetime ASC**